Using Uniswap V3 to swap 2 ERC20 tokens on Amoy Testnet
I'm quite new to blockchain and uniswap in general, I have deployed 2 erc20 tokens on Amoy testnet.
TokenA and TokenB
I would like to be able to swap between TokenA and TokenB by using uniswap v3.
From what I read in uniswap document, it seems uniswap currently doesn't support Amoy testnet.
Is it mean I'm unable to test it?
Or is there other way to do swap on amoy network?

As of now, there's no official support, but you can deploy uniswap contracts by urself, or you can also use the ones deployed by other devs.
for example this one - https://amoy.polygonscan.com/address/0x586a31a288e178369fff020ba63d2224cf8661e9#code

ey everyone, I'm really frustrated right now.
I've been trying to test my smart contract, which uses Uniswap V3, on various testnets like Sepolia, Mumbai, Amoy, and even Goerli. But Uniswap V3 doesn't seem to work on any of these testnets! I need to understand: **where where can I actually run my tests with Uniswap V3? This is critical for my development process,
I’m using AAVE v3 alongside Uniswap V3, but it's im
Can someone please help clarify where Uniswap V3 works for testing, or if there’s an alternative I should be using? I’m not a developer by profession, and I’ve been burned in the past by people who didn’t take the time to help. I really need patience and clear guidance here.

You can look at Sepolia testnet addresses here: https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/deployments/ethereum-deployments
If you need more information open a new question!
